# How correct save several entities in one transient to a database?

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

Can you show a better way to save two entities to a database?
I think my code terrible.
I receive a DTO with two entities (between them relation one to one).

I validate fields in these entities. If I receive an error, I shouldn't save anything.

My logic:
1. I need to save the first entity;
2. Set the id from the first entity to the second entity; (I'll receive id if I save an entity. That's why I can't do it instantly)
3. Save the second entity.
4. If I receive an error I delete the first saved entity.

```
@PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody DTOClient dtoClient)  {
        ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        Optional<Client> clientFromDB = Optional.empty();
        Optional<Skill> skillFromDB =  Optional.empty();

            try{
                clientFromDB = Optional.ofNullable(this.clientService.save(dtoClient.getClient()));
                dtoClient.getSkill().setClient(clientFromDB.get());
                skillFromDB = Optional.ofNullable(this.skillService.save(dtoClient.getSkill()));

                if (clientFromDB.isPresent() && skillFromDB.isPresent()) {
                    responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }catch (RuntimeException ex){
                clientService.deleteById(clientFromDB.get().getId());
            }
        return responseEntity;
        }
```

Thank you for help! 
Update.
Now, I don't need to check this exception.
When I do it, I see two insert request to the database. Is it correct?
Can I do it with one request?

```
dtoClient().getSkill().setClient(dtoClient().getClient())
skillFromDB = Optional.ofNullable(this.skillService.save(dtoClient.getSkill()));
```

Comment: That code should be in a service method which itself would be annotated with `@Transactional` next to that, do proper JPA mapping and you can save everything in one go instead of having to manually mess around with ids.

Comment: Thank you! Can you show an example of JPA mapping?

Comment: You should only be saving the skill, which should have an `@OneToMany` or `@OneToOne` annotation on the `Client` field and make sure you set the `cascade` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand. Why should I save only the skill and it step will save a client?

Comment: Because of the cascading it will store that as well.

Comment: Thank you all! I updated my question.

Comment: Ofcourse you will see to insert statements... There are 2 records inserted in 2 different tables.